# RxView.clicks(view).subscribe vs view.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, view, rx-java

What is the benefit of using `RxView.clicks(view).subscribe` rather than normal `view.setOnClickListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many useful usecases that you can have using `RxView`.

`setOnClickListener` only notifies when user clicks a `View`.

But `RxView` make it possible to handle this UI-action and perform many of `Rx-Java` useful methods on input.

**For example:**

If impatient user clicks button fast and several times, and this clicks calls for some long running operations, it will be the problem, right?

With `RxView` you can easily add some pause between handling this clicks. And it will be very useful:

```
RxView.clicks(mSearchBtn)
        .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe(s -> {
            // perform some actions
        });
```

Or if you perform some network call and not want to abort it:

```
boolean isRequestSended = true;
RxView.clicks(mSearchBtn)
        .skipWhile(new Predicate<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Object o) throws Exception {
                        return isRequestSended
                    }
                })
        .subscribe(s -> {
            // isRequestSended = false
        });
```

And many of another examples.

Many of usescases you can check in [this post](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.view.RxView)